# Laravel Cascade Insert throught HasMany relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, save, has-many, cascade

I'm newbie in laravel and I want to persist Master/Detail in one step!

I have the follows classes

Master => hasMany(Items)

and

Item => belongsTo(Master)

So, in my Controller I want to create an instance of Master and many instances of Items and persist all of them in one step... like that

```
    $master = new  Master();
    $master->field = $someField;

    foreach ($myArray as $var) {
        $item = new  Item();
        $item->someField =  $field;
        // I suppose I need to relate Item with master, but... how?
    }

and here y want to persist all objectes like that
$master->save(); and Eloquent must to persist Master and Items...
```

but I prefer do that without persist Master first...

Is it possible?
I don't understand how to do it...

Thanks in advance

Nicolas

Comment: What do you mean by "one step", and why are you trying to do that? Because no matter what, Laravel will need to run multiple insert statements to save to more than one table.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent data inconsistency in the event of failures (use transactions), or just organize the code differently so that all of the "save" actions are together (use saveMany())?

Comment: That's right!... Firstly... excuse me my English... "One step" means "One go"... or something like that…
I'm trying to save all items in one transaction and I want to the ORM manages it for me… In Java is pretty common it happen... I fill my collection (composition in UML) and when I save the master record, the ORM inserts all items in one transaction. Is it possible in laravel?  Thank you very much for answering my ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the whole thing with the `transaction()` method from the `DB` facade:

```
$bar = 'bar';

DB::transaction(function () use ($bar) {
    $master = new  Master();
    $master->foo = $bar;

    $items = [];
    foreach ($myArray as $var) {
        $item = new  Item();
        $item->someField =  $field;

        $items[] = $item;
    }

    $master->save();
    $master->items()->saveMany($items);
});
```

This will automatically catch any exception, rollback the transaction, and re-throw.

Or you can do it manually with `DB::beginTransaction()`, `DB::rollBack()`, and `DB::commit()`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#database-transactions

Answer (score 0):

Since the master has an items, the master must be saved first, so we have the master ID and we can associate with the items.
Change the code this way

```
$master = new  Master();
$master->field = $someField;
$master->save(); 

foreach ($myArray as $var) {
    $item = new  Item();
    $item->someField =  $field;
    $item->master_id =  $master->id;
    $item->save();
}
```

Comment: Yes, of Course! But I have to persist all records in one go..For this reason I've said without persist master first...In java that's possible... But in Laravel I don't know... Anyway thank you very much for your answer